# 4-я область видимости свойства

Tags: php

Есть в php стандартный  класс `MySQLi`.

Я создаю собственный класс и наследую от класса `MySQLi` все его методы и свойства.

Хочу поменять свойство `string $error` – выдаёт фатальную ошибку.

Считать я данное свойство могу. Записать – нет.

Как я знаю, есть 3 вида доступа: `public`, `private` и `protected`. Но при использовании любого из них нельзя добиться такого же результата.

Вывод:  получается, есть ещё 4-й метод доступа к свойству?

> `Fatal error: Db::__construct() [<a href='db.--construct'>db.--construct</a>]: Cannot write property in Y:\hom...`

Comment: @goodini, покажите, как пытаетесь задать значение.

Comment: В конструкторе моего класса $this->error='hi';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный класс MySQLi является встроенным, он реализован в расширении Mysqli на С, а не на PHP.
Свойство error реализовано как недоступное для записи.

Исходник: [`mysqli_prop.c,` строка `449`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ee2d5776fafff70a8149aa2050ded2f1397b6847/ext/mysqli/mysqli_prop.c#L449)

Comment: свойство которое я унаследовал от этого класса в моем классе чем является? константой? но это константа процессе выполнения изменяется самим классом, интересно как это самому реализовать...

Comment: Нет, это не константа. Просто это такое свойство, при установке которого из PHP выскакивет ошибка.

На PHP это можно реализовать с помощью [магических методов `__get()` и `__set()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: а можно создать константу в виде ссылки на какую нибудь переменю, или область памяти, хоть как нибудь?